Comparing slopes of regression models on different data
Let's say, we have two dependent variables: $y_1$ and $y_2$, and these dependent variables depend on their own exogenous regressors:
$$y_1 = \beta_0 + \beta_1 x_1 + \epsilon_1$$
$$y_2 = \gamma_0 + \gamma_1 x_2 + \epsilon_2$$
Where the length $n_k$ of $y_1$ and $y_2$ does not necessarily need to be the same. Assume $n_1 \neq n_2$.
In both cases, I could estimate a regression model and obtain estimates of parameters. Then, I could test these parameters by t-test if they significantly differ from a certain value. So, I could ask one model, whether the value of its parameter is the same as the estimated value of the parameter in the second model:
$$\frac{\hat{\beta_1} - \hat{\gamma_1}}{\text{s.d.}(\hat{\beta_1})} \sim t(n_1 - 2)$$
And analogically for $\hat{\gamma_1}$...
BUT, is there a way how to compare both of these parameters simultaneously if they are statistically indistinguishable?

The construction of your question is ambiguous.  Are you trying to ask how to test the hypothesis $\beta_1=\gamma_1$?

yes. I am trying to ask how to identify, whether the slope in first model is statistically the same as the slope in the second model.

To run a t-test (or any other test for that matter), you need multiple observations; how do you propose to obtain multiple observations of $\beta_1$ and $\gamma_1$? You could sub-sample, but these observations would be highly correlated (i.e. not independent, so a t-test would not be valid?)

@jginestet I understand the question differently: using multiple observations in two separate OLS regressions, the OP has obtained two independent estimates and variances of those estimates.  This sounds like a standard two-sample t-test situation.  As I'm sure you know, quite a few unstated assumptions go into this conclusion, so it would be nice to have a few more details about the observations and perhaps even the models and even about the distributions of their residuals.

@whuber I think you understand it right. Let's say, for simplicity, we could start such that the standard assumptions for using OLS are satisfied. All variables are continuous and quantitative, and have similar but not the same interpretation ($y_1$ is similar in meaning to $y_2$, such as both can be quantities purchased, but of different products. Analogically, $x_1$ and $x_2$ can be prices but of different products). Additionally, number of observations and the data themselves are different.

You can construct an approximate test of $\beta_1 \neq \gamma_1$ in much the same way as a two-sample $t$-test with unequal variances, see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Welch%27s_t-test, as the underlying theory applies analogously also in this case provided that the errors in the two regressions are iid normal.

Or are you willing to assume that $\operatorname{Var}\epsilon_1=\operatorname{Var}\epsilon_2$?  If so, this can be treated as a single regression model and a linear hypothesis.

For a t-test comparing $\beta_1$ and $\gamma_1$ to be valid, would that not assume that $x_1, x_2, y_1, y_2$ are all normally distributed? Given that $\beta_1=\frac {Cov(x,y)} {Var(x)}$? That is a pretty demanding assumption...

This reference https://www-sciencedirect-com.libaccess.sjlibrary.org/science/article/pii/S000326701400511X?via%3Dihub may be helpful in evaluating when/if a t-test is a proper way of comparing coefficients of an OLS.

@JarleTufto Why can I treat it as single model if $VAR(\epsilon_1) = VAR(\epsilon_2)$? And how would the model look like? I cannot directly combine both dependent variables into a single one such as $y = comb(y_1, y_2)$ because then the dimension with $x_1$ and $x_2$ would not fit, or can I? Would I also need to combine $x = comb(x_1, x_2)$ and add a dummy $D = 1 \text{ if } x_1 \neq \text{ NA}$? Then, if the dummy is non-zero, I would say that the $\gamma_1 \neq \beta_1$?

@jginestet Why does the interpretation of a coefficient through cov/var formula causes the normal distribution of both regressors and dependent variables to be pretty demanding? When I simulated it, I tried a few different distibutions and the normally distributed regressors worked just fine. By the way, could you please provide a name of the article, I cannot access it.

@Athaeneus I'm only saying that you may want to assume equal error variances if this is reasonable by your own judgement.  But if the two regressions are from different types of experiments, then the error variances would presumably almost surely be differerent.

@Athaeneus, article is "J.M. Andrade, M.G. Estévez-Pérez, Statistical comparison of the slopes of two regression lines: A tutorial, Analytica Chimica Acta, Volume 838, 2014. For the t-test to be valid,the sampling distribution of $\beta_1$ needs to be normal, and that happens when the $x_i's, y_i's$ are normally distributed. That is a demanding assumption (i.e. not easy to demonstrate in real samples).
